# run buildbot on Windows XP

Tags: windows, build-automation, buildbot, nightly-build, dailybuilds

I recently stumbled over buildbot and wanted to give it a try.
My problem is that I have to run it under Windows because we don't use Linux on workstations or servers in my company.

I've already tried different installations:
python 2.6, Twisted-9.0.0-py2.6, buildbot 0.7.12
python 2.6, pywin32-214-py2.6, Twisted-9.0.0-py2.6, buildbot 0.7.12
python 2.4, pywin32-214-py2.4, Twisted-9.0.0-py2.4, buildbot 0.7.12

and tried to run it in a Windows XP VM.

In all installations I ran the buildbot test suite and got several errors and the buildbot documentation sais that no test should fail.

Does anybody here have experience with buildbot under Windows?
Is it worth the pain or do I have to use Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it with Python 2.4 and Twisted 2.5 (old, I know). Also, make sure you have ZopeInterface installed.

I have personally never used it with Windows, but will try and let you know what results I get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that many people are running buildmasters on Windows.

I have a Windows buildslave running:

- buildbot 0.8.0
- twisted 10.0.0
- zopeinterface 3.6.1

which appears to work fine though haven't tried the test set.